# Want to compare two string in handlebars view in node js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compare, handlebars.js

I want to do some comparisons in a handlebars template in an express-nodejs app.

It looks something like this:

```
{{# if(x==y)}}
    equal string
 {{else}}
    not equal string
 {{/if}}
```

I already installed the handlebars and express-handlebars packages. I read about the handlebars helpers but couldn't figure out a way to use them properly. I tried to add the helpers in the app.js file in my app, but I couldn't use them in my template file in view.

Any help would be helpful and appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `is` function like this :

```
 {{#is x "my_string"}}
     x is "my_string"
 {{else}}
     x isn't "my_string"
 {{/is}}
```

Otherwise, you can use this famous helper :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this)
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this)
    }
})
```

And use it like this :

```
{{#if_equal x "my_string"}}
     x is "my_string"
{{else}}
     x isn't "my_string"
{{/if_equal}}
```

Comment: Thanks @hardrien for helping me. 
Where do i put the registerHelper either in app.js or router js file(index.js)

Comment: Wherever you want in a JavaScript that will be executed client side ;) (but after loading the `handlebar.js` library)

Comment: you mean i should put the Handlebars.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts){..........} in template file?

Comment: Only just after the script that loads `handlebar.js`.

Comment: TypeError: expressHbs.registerHelper is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\xampp\htdocs\node-todo\app.js:29:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
.....................
.........................
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Can you show me the code of the file that loads `handlebar.js`?

Comment: i load the var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars'); in app.js, this file is situated on root level

Comment: I see, so can you list me the HTML files that you are using?

Comment: Below is the fiddle link. 
https://jsfiddle.net/3kcnnr6y/

I want to modify the select dropdown suing the conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129721/discussion-between-rahul-mangal-and-hadrien-toma).